# MySQL several IDs in one row join with another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, swift, join

I'm stack in the following: I have 2 tables: Users and Follow. Users table contains 2 columns: ID and Fullname. Follow table contains 2 columns: Follower_ID and Following_ID. It shows that Smith is following Jane.
Now I want an output that shows the full names of both users.

PLEASE HELP!

---

```
Table Users:
ID | 1, 2

Fullname | Smith, Jane
```

---

```
Table Follow:
Follower_ID | 1

Following_ID | 2
```

---

Required Output:

```
Follower_ID | 1

Follower_fullname | Smith

Following_ID | 2

Following_fullname | Jane
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use twice inner join with user table

```
select 
 a.Follower_ID
, c.Fullname as Follower_Fullname
, a.Following_ID
, b.Fullname  as Following_Fullname
from Follow as a 
inner join Users as b on b.ID = a.Following_ID
inner join Users as c on c.ID = a.Follower_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my week-time. :)